# CSS filter doesn't apply on hover in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have noticed that applying a change to `filter` property on hover leads to a weird behavior in Safari 16.2 on macOS:

- it doesn't actually change on hover
- it does partly change if you click on the text, which definitely is not a desired behavior

Using `-webkit-filter` doesn't help either.

```css
/* problem-relevant CSS */

div{
  background: red;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
div:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

/* some further styling for readability */

div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Me</div>
```

Here's how it looks (GIF):

> [image]

What could be done about that?

Comment: *Meta notice*: though this q-a pair may not seem like serving any a useful purpose at a first glance, it is still a debugging problem. In a matter of fact, it just happens pretty often that on each misbehavior you're most likely blaming yourself, which is not something you should do here since *it's actually a rendering bug*. It took me a while to understand it wasn't me who made a mistake, since I'm generally quite generous on micro-mistakes, so I decided to post it here for a future reference.

Answer (score 1):

This appears be a rendering bug of webkit.

I've found a couple of ways to workaround it:

- using `transform` without actually transforming anything (e.g., `scale(1)`) somehow fixes this issue
- a short `transition:0.05s` would help (although creating an unwanted transition), any longer transition solves the problem either (in a case you generally wanted to put transition here, you would probably never found this question)

Fun fact: and an *even shorter* transition (i.e. `0.03s`) doesn't fix anything.

```css
/* solution-relevant CSS */

div{
  background: red;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
div:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1);
}

/* some further styling for readability */

div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Me</div>
```